# app.config controler and writer

Tags: c#, app-config, tex

I need help with app.config control and writing. I have latex project. And I need to write configuration to change chapter of my PDF. For example I have 3chapters, but I don't need 2chapter now. So I want to `\include` in my `main tex` only `\include chap1` and `\include chap3`. I have app.config.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration>
     <appSettings>
        <add key="\include" value="chap1" />
        <add key="\include" value="chap2" />
        <add key="\include" value="chap3" />
     </appSettings>
    </configuration>
```

With what methods I can control and use this config. Is it possible at all?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app.config is just an XML file... so for a quick and easy solution to a simple config file just treat it as so:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

// Create a list just in case you want to remove specific elements later
List<XElement> toRemove = new List<XElement>();

// Load the config file
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("app.config");

// Get the appSettings element as a parent
XContainer appSettings = doc.Element("configuration").Element("appSettings");

// step through the "add" elements
foreach (XElement xe in appSettings.Elements("add"))
{
    // Get the values
    string addKey = xe.Attribute("key").Value;
    string addValue = xe.Attribute("value").Value;

    // if you want to remove it...
    if (addValue == "something")
    {
        // you can't remove it directly in the foreach loop since it breaks the enumerable
        // add it to a list and do it later
        toRemove.Add(xe);
    }
}

// Remove the elements you've selected
foreach (XElement xe in toRemove)
{
    xe.Remove();
}

// Add any new Elements that you want
appSettings.Add(new XElement("add", 
    new XAttribute("key", "\\inculde"),
    new XAttribute("value", "chapX")));
```

If you know exactly what you want to do you could probably use more targeted solutions.

However, for your scenario you might want to load this add elements into a collection, process them as you want (add/remove/update etc...) then write them back out again as "add" elements in the .config file.